# how to reset metabox excerpt to open

Tags: metabox, excerpt

For some reason the excerpt box on the new posts page (`post-new.php`) is always closed. I can alter that with firebug, but it should be open anyway.

There is a "closed" class being added by someone somewhere, but it is unwanted. Is there any fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Wordpress saves the open/close state of these metaboxes each time you toggle it. This is done via javascript, requesting an ajax endpoint on the server.

You need to find out if that request is still send or not. If it's not send (e.g. javascript error, blocked by some plugin), then you found the cause.

If it is send, you need to find out if the new state is successfully [stored inside the database](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4381/make-custom-metaboxes-collapse-by-default/4383#4383). If it is not stored inside the database, you found the cause.

If it is stored into the database, you need to find out if it is read out of the database. If it is not read out of the database, then you found the cause.

If it is read out of the database you need to find out if it get's correctly applied as the metabox class either via the pages response or via some additional javascript / ajax hook. I don't remember from mind if there is something like the latter as well. If not, you found the cause.

If it does, well then I have no additional idea what the cause of the error might be right away, but I'm pretty sure if you debug it that far, you found the cause ;)

More information is available here:

- [Make Custom Metaboxes Collapse by Default](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4381/make-custom-metaboxes-collapse-by-default)

Comment: Dear Hakre, Many thanks for the clues. I accessed the database and found there was an entry: INSERT INTO `wp_usermeta` VALUES (17, 1, 'closedpostboxes_post', 'a:1:{i:0;s:11:"postexcerpt";}'); I changed that to INSERT INTO `wp_usermeta` VALUES (17, 1, 'closedpostboxes_post', 'a:0:{}'); and everything seems to be OK now. I'm sure glad there's guys like you around :-)